# foreach all the post

Tags: php, posts

How to i foreach the post title like below.
this is what i want below

```
function get_all_post_for_search() {
    return array (
      array(
        'name' => "Hello Project",
        'thumb' => '/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/photo-1442473483905-95eb436675f1.jpeg',
        'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit..'
      ),
      array(
        'name' => "Another Project",
        'thumb' => '/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/photo-1449024540548-94f5d5a59230-1.jpeg',
        'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit..'
      )
    );
}
```

this is my code

```
function all_post_data(){

    $args = array (
        'post_type'              => 'post',
        'pagination'             => FALSE,
        'suppress_filters'       => FALSE
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()):
            $query->the_post();

            $post_id = get_the_id();
            $the_title = get_the_title();
            $thumbs = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $des = get_the_content();
            $search_data = [];

                  $img_url = $thumb['url'];

                  if(is_array($thumb) && $img_url){
                      $search_data[] = array(
                          'name' => $the_title,
                          'thumb' => $img_url,
                          'desc' => $des
                      );
                  }       
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    var_dump($search_data);
}
```

Comment: What is the current output ?

Comment: just empty  array:(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

working code

```
function list_post_data(){
   $args="SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.`post_type` = 'post' AND wp_posts.`post_status` = 'publish'";

    $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'post'
            );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    $array = array();

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        global $post;
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        $array[] = array(
            //'id' => get_the_ID(),
            'name' => get_the_title(),
            'thumb' => $url,
            'desc' => get_the_content()
        );

    endwhile;

   // wp_reset_query();
    ob_clean();
    //echo json_encode($array);
    var_dump($array);
    exit();
}
```

result is

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'test post' (length=9)
      'thumb' => boolean false
      'desc' => string 'dfgrgsrga' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Hello world!' (length=12)
      'thumb' => string 'http://lfigp-new.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/valentine-cake_1x.png' (length=69)
      'desc' => string 'Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!' (length=85)
```

Comment: Also, explain what you have done and how the code works. Code dumping are poor quality answers. Please see [answer]

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many errors:-

- `$thumbs` isn't used anywhere.
- `$img_url = $thumb['url'];` undefined variable
- `if(is_array($thumb) && $img_url)` always `false` because of second point.
- `$search_data = [];` should be outside of loop.

Check the correct part of code

```
$search_data = [];
if($query->have_posts()):
    while($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();

        $img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

        if(!empty($img_url)){
            $search_data[] = array(
                'name' => get_the_title(),
                'thumb' => $img_url,
                'desc' => get_the_content()
            );
        }       
    endwhile;
endif;
```

> NOTE: `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` is only available from WordPress
>   4.4

Comment: I thinks this code is working

Comment: What do you mean by _think_ ? It is really working or not working ?